# What type of hash er encryption?

Tags: encryption, hash

I just want to ask if someone have an idea about the type of this hash or encryption?
PWB1AD8APWA/AD8APWA/AD8AGGA/AD8APWA/AD8APWA/AA4ARQBCAA==

Comment: Looks like the last line of something base64-y...

Comment: This might help you [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?][1]


  [1]: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely base64.  But what is encoded in the base64 is next question.

```
  $ echo "PWB1AD8APWA/AD8APWA/AD8AGGA/AD8APWA/AD8APWA/AA4ARQBCAA==" | openssl enc -d -base64 -out b.1 ; hexdump b.1
  00000 3d 60 75 00 3f 00 3d 60   3f 00 3f 00 3d 60 3f 00     =`u.?.=`?.?.=`?.
  00010 3f 00 18 60 3f 00 3f 00   3d 60 3f 00 3f 00 3d 60     ?..`?.?.=`?.?.=`
  00020 3f 00 0e 00 45 00 42 00                               ?...E.B.
```

This is the decode of the base64.  Now you would have to figure out what this data could be.
One clue is that it is 40 bytes.  Only some encryption algorithms can generate 40 bytes (Not
a multiple of 16).  For example aes256 would be a multiple of 16, where des is multiples of 8.